# What's the Cantonese/Mandarin equivalent of "condone"?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

These two dictionaries don't have entries for "condone."

- https://www.yellowbridge.com
- http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/scripts/wordsearch.php?level=0

The Google translate answer is 縱容, which seems quite wrong at least for Cantonese.

What's the Cantonese/Mandarin translation for condone?

Comment: You might want to give some context for what you're looking for - an example English sentence perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some words that are similar in meaning to condone (and indeed some dictionaries even translate them to condone):

• 容忍 or 容受 -> tolerate; put up with.

• 赦免 -> absolve, excuse, remit a punishment

The essence of condone is to accept with reluctance -- consequently, it's usually used in the negative in English (as in "We do not condone the violence") or with a negative connotation ("They took the silence to indicate that she condoned their behavior" is a sentence that implies the behavior is somehow "wrong"). With this in mind, I feel 容忍 (in Mandarin at least) works well.

Comment: 容忍 seems right based on a 3rd dictionary used. thanks!